# In a pre-commit-hook is there a way to validate the "state after commit" of the checkout folder?

Tags: git, static-analysis, pre-commit-hook

I'd like to run static checks (e.g. `mypy`, `pylint`) in a `pre-commit` hook. My current naive approach (just running those checks in the `pre-commit` hook) gives me false negatives and false positives because of non-staged changes and untracked files.

So what I *actually* want to do is to readily create the commit, clean the workspace by stashing away unstaged and untracked local changes, and then run the test.

Of course I could make an alias for this in order to make things easier, but then I would not be allowed to `git commit` directly any more (also I'd have to share the git config file).

I also could use the `pre-commit` hook, but I don't see a way to allow `git commit -m"foo" file1 file2` (i.e. providing file names instead of staging all changes before).

Is there an intended (or even built in) way to do check "the state after the commit excluding local modifications (untracked and unstaged)" that works with

```
git commit -m"foo" file1 file2
```

Comment: You're looking for https://pre-commit.com/ it does what you describe: it stashes unstaged changes before running the hooks you enable.

Comment: You might consider turning this into an answer in order to harvest the deserved reputation. Though, I'll wait for a day or two in the hope in 2022 some built-in-approach pops up. Can't see a reason why this is not the default behavior..

Comment: It's not the default behaviour because there's actually quite a bit of machinery involved, and a lot of corner cases. Git itself says that commit just commits what's staged and so you should be able to expect that your unstaged changes stay untouched. pre-commit violates that is a careful way, but there are corner cases: what if a hook makes changes that conflict with unstaged changes? (e.g., if black is one of your hooks, that's easy to imagine). I've never had the situation, so I don't know what pre-commit does in that case, but now I'll have to test, I'm curious.

Comment: I should add... It's the responsibility of the pre commit hook writer to scan the index rather than the files on the file system. Git provides all the necessary tools for it, but it's not that easy to do. That's why I'm glad I can use pre-commit for my Python projects and Husky for my Node projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the responsibility of the commit hook writer to query the index rather than the files in the sandbox. It's all doable, but somewhat tricky. Fortunately, it's all been done before.

The Python module pre-commit will stash unstaged changes for you, run all the hooks you request in your configuration file, and then pop the stash back afterwards.

Ref: https://pre-commit.com/

If you're working with Node, an excellent alternative written in JS is Husky. It implements many Git hooks and integrates very easily in any Node project.

Ref: https://typicode.github.io/husky

You can use either of these tools with projects in any language, but it's easiest to match languages because pre-commit can be in your `requirements.dev.txt` and husky in your `package.json` so they get installed with the rest of your dev environment with minimal additional dependencies.